# Azure SQL Server is it possible read from secondary node[readonly] and write to ReadWrite

Tags: sql-server, azure

I have admin account,

I need a query to run everyday.
This query is heavy and cannot run on production server.
"selecting" is takes 30 mins.
So I need to use azure readonly secondary node.
When It runs on secondary node It doesnt lock production server.

after the select, output needs to be inserted to a table.
Table is in prod but just stored for reports.
This is not risky.

I can do that in C# with 2 connection strings, but I want to do it in SQL server.
Is it possible to select from [secondary node] and write to production server ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish that using 4 part name and that is using a [Linked Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15)
Pushing data using linked server would be ok but if you have lots of data to move between servers then **pulling** it will work better (save the data to a db not participating in Availability Group and execute a procedure on the remote (your Primary Replica) server that pulls the desired data).

Regardless of the above the fact the query takes so long to complete indicates there may be room for improvement, or possibly a missing index.